# How do I determine the name of the network interface I created with netlink?

Tags: linux, netlink

I am using Netlink to create a network interface without specifying the name. Netlink chooses a name for the new interface (like for example "vlan0"), but I do not know how to figure this name out.

My function calls are (in pseudo code):

```
link = rtnl_link_alloc();
rtnl_link_set_type(link, kind));
rtnl_link_add(sk, link, NLM_F_CREATE));
```

The interface is created without errors but calling `rtnl_link_get_name(link)` or `rtnl_link_get_ifindex(link)` but fail after the call to `rtnl_link_add()`.

So how can I determine the name of the new interface?

Comment: You should probably provide something more than pseudocode (also see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). According to [`rtnetlink (7)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html), it looks like it is available in the `ifinfomsg` or `nlmsghdr` structs when `rta_type` is `IFLA_IFNAME`. With a few useful symbols, it looks like sample code is available at [Howto get a list of network interfaces in Linux, Part 3](https://iijean.blogspot.com/2010/03/howto-get-list-of-network-interfaces-in.html).